# sigfillset is not setting signal bits

Tags: 12.04, fedora, signal

I am having this strange problem! My code is very simple.

```
    #include<stdio.h>    
    #include<unistd.h>    
    #include<signal.h>      
    #include<stdlib.h>    
main()    
{    
  sigset_t signal ;    
  printf("Value of signal before sigfil is %x\n",signal) ;    
  sigemptyset(&signal);    
  printf("Value of signal after sigempty is %x\n",signal) ;    
  sigfillset(&signal) ;    
  printf("Value of signal after sigfil is %x\n",signal) ;    
}
```

But every time I compile and run the code, I am getting some random values.
Example:

```
Value of signal before sigfil is bf77c638    
Value of signal after sigempty is 1a934000    
Value of signal after sigfil is 1a934000
```

I tried this on Ubuntu 12.10 and Fedora. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of sigset_t should give you a clue, its not a plain int, it's more complex:

Note the array of words within __val.

```
# define _SIGSET_NWORDS (1024 / (8 * sizeof (unsigned long int)))
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long int __val[_SIGSET_NWORDS];
} __sigset_t;
```

You could try:

```
signal.__val[0];
```

Note that you should expect garbage in the initial print from the stack.

Of course you shouldn't be looking within this structure in the first place since it is supposed to be opaque. But it is useful for debugging sometimes.